# Playing with/editing partition table

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

While playing with GParted my partition table was damaged in the sense that an extended partition ended after the end of disk.

To fix it I used TestDisk to backup the current partition table and removed the partition losing quite a lot of data. When I looked at the backup TestDisk made, it's a text file with just the start and end of partitions written in clear text.

I was wondering if I could edit them, reducing the size of the offending partition and restoring the backup file using TestDisk, thus changing the partition size in the partition table without removing the entry.

Can I do that keeping in mind that the offending partition is empty near the end so no data loss would occur from me moving the boundary of the partition in the partition table?

Comment: I second Mehrdad, and have come to wish you luck both with the issue and finding somebody macho enough to help you out. [May the Schwartz be with you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceballs).

Comment: Are the *beginning* few sectors of the partition still intact?

Answer (score 1):

If the beginning few sectors of the partition are intact, take a look at [EASEUS Partition Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/).

Answer (score 0):

If you still remember your partition parameters, try [ranish partition manager](http://www.ranish.com/part/). I used it back then when I was still a  tinkerer..